# binding a service to multiple activities

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

My service is correctly binded to my first activity but when I try to bind it to a second activity it does not work
Here is the code of onresume and on pause of my first activity

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            service = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            shareInfos.this.service = (IService) service;
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent(this, shareInfos.class), connection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (service != null) {
        service = null;
        unbindService(connection);
    }
}
```

I did the same to my second activity but when I try to use the service it is always null
Here is the code of my second activity:

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            service = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            shareInfos.this.service = (IService) service;
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent(this, shareInfos.class), connection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (service != null) {
        service = null;
        unbindService(connection);
    }
}
```

Thats is the code of my service:

```
public class ExampleService extends AbstractService {
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "ExampleService";
public ExampleService() {
    super(SERVICE_NAME);
}
@Override
public AbstractRegistration getRegistration() {
    return new AbstractRegistration() {
        @Override
        public String getApplicationName() {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.application_name);
        }
        @Override
        public String getApplicationDescription() {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.application_description);
        }
        @Override
        public PendingIntent getApplicationSettings() {
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExampleActivity.class), 0);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean requiresStorage() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean requiresQueries() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean requiresRecognition() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

}

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="eu.gambas.example.android" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="eu.gambas.permission.ACCESS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/application_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.egm.exampleandroid.ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/application_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.egm.exampleandroid.ResultActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.egm.exampleandroid.shareInfos" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.egm.exampleandroid.testActivity" />
    <service
        android:name="com.example.egm.exampleandroid.ExampleService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="eu.gambas.action.start" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="eu.gambas.action.stop" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="eu.gambas.action.result" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Lets see that manifest por favor.

Comment: Services across many activities gets messy. There are two ways I'd go about it. I'd either subclass Application class and do some custom work. The second way is to convert your multiple activities to fragments, that way it'll make the service work substantially better!

Comment: I added my manifest file into my question. Concerning the use of fragments, how to bind them to the service? Thanks!

Comment: you just have to bind the parent activity and thats it.

Comment: then reference the parent activity with getActivity().

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the same object of the Service call in both the activities. The best way to do it will be to extend the Application class where you have to write code to start service and to stop.Then you can access the service from any activity.

```
    public class AppController extends Application {

     private static AppController mInstance;
     private ExampleService service;
     public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
            return mInstance;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }
    public void startService(){
    //start your service

    }
    public void stopService(){
    //stop service
    }
    public ExampleService getService(){
    }
    }
```

Now to get the service from activity

```
AppController.getInstance().getService();
```

Comment: @Jlthin could you flesh this out a little bit more? Specifically, what should go into the getService method? Does startService get called in onCreate()?

Comment: Isn't it a very bad practice to save references to objects in the Application class?  http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/